# Need to sum total of device parts chosen by comboclick

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to sum the total cost of the device parts for a project. The device part numbers are chosen using a drop down menu on comboclick and a label shows the cost of the part next to it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and can't seem to find a similar situation online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *  

root = Tk()
root.title('Device Cost')
root.geometry("400x200")

total1 = 0
total2 = 0

def comboclick1(event):
    if myCombo1.get() == Model[1]:
        myLabel1 = Label(root, text=ModelCost[1]).grid(row=0,column=1)
        total1 = int(ModelCost[1])
    else:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=' ').grid(row=0,column=1)
        total1 = 0

def comboclick2(event):
    if myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[1]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[1]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[1]
    elif myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[2]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[2]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[2]
    elif myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[3]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[3]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[3]
    else:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=' ').grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = 0

Model = [
"Choose One",
"Device"
]

ModelCost = [
"",
1000
]

SpindleTooling = [
"Choose One",
"106",
"107",
"108"
] 

SpindleToolingCost = [
"",
1,
2,
3
] 

myCombo1 = ttk.Combobox(root, value=Model)
myCombo1.current(0)
myCombo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",comboclick1)
myCombo1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

myCombo2 = ttk.Combobox(root, value=SpindleTooling)
myCombo2.current(0)
myCombo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",comboclick2)
myCombo2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

mytotal = [total1,total2]
total = sum(mytotal)
print("My total is",total)

myLabel4 = Label(root, text="Total").grid(row=3,column=0)
myLabel4 = Label(root, text=total).grid(row=3,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem actually ?

Comment: My total is just 0. It sums the initialized total components and doesn't sum the total components generated when the comboclicks are used.

Comment: Please create a [___Minimal___, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I shortened the code a bit more, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly telling Python to sum 0 and 0, and that is, logically, 0:

> ```py
> mytotal = [total1,total2]
> total = sum(mytotal)
> print("My total is",total)
> ```

Above is equivalent to:

```py
print(sum(0, 0))
```

You should move that code part into your `comboclick1` and `comboclick2` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that constnly changes the value of the total when necessary. It will run every 10 milliseconds (0.01 second), using `root.after(1, check)`:

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Device Cost')
root.geometry("400x200")

total1 = 0
total2 = 0

def comboclick1(event):
    global total1
    if myCombo1.get() == Model[1]:
        myLabel1 = Label(root, text=ModelCost[1]).grid(row=0,column=1)
        total1 = int(ModelCost[1])
        print(total1)
    else:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=' ').grid(row=0,column=1)
        total1 = 0


def comboclick2(event):
    global total2

    if myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[1]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[1]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[1]
    elif myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[2]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[2]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[2]
    elif myCombo2.get() == SpindleTooling[3]:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=SpindleToolingCost[3]).grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = SpindleToolingCost[3]
    else:
        myLabel2 = Label(root, text=' ').grid(row=1,column=1)
        total2 = 0


def check():
    total_label = Label(root, text=total)
    total_label.grid(row=3, column=1)

    total_label.config(text=sum([int(total1), int(total2)]))

    root.after(10, check)


Model = [
"Choose One",
"Device"
]

ModelCost = [
"",
1000
]

SpindleTooling = [
"Choose One",
"106",
"107",
"108"
]

SpindleToolingCost = [
"",
1,
2,
3
]

myCombo1 = ttk.Combobox(root, value=Model)
myCombo1.current(0)
myCombo1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",comboclick1)
myCombo1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

myCombo2 = ttk.Combobox(root, value=SpindleTooling)
myCombo2.current(0)
myCombo2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",comboclick2)
myCombo2.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

mytotal = [total1,total2]
total = sum(mytotal)
print("My total is",total)

myLabel4 = Label(root, text="Total").grid(row=3, column=0)

check()
root.mainloop()
```